# "Syncing" mail adress which is handled by several people

Tags: email, sync, imap

I have to set up and maintain mailserver, webserver, etc. for an organisation.

I have a virtual server with Ubuntu on it. So I basically have full control over the server.

The organisation has a info@organisation address. Two people are responsible to read and react to those mails. But now we get a syncing problem. It would sure be possible that person 1 always informs person 2 if a mail was handled. One could also use pop3 and just download the mail, so that the other person just does not see the mail. But that is also a problem, because both should be able to see all the received mail onto this address. IMAP is also no solution, because then person 2 does not know if person one has just received the mail but not handled it...

Do you know a solution for that? I am talking about some software :-) Or solution which involves configuration of mailserver...

Comment: This is not an email issue at all. What you need is some kind of helpdesk software with ability to receive tickets by email. It would allow whoever sees the ticket first to claim it, so the other person would know that the first is working on it. Also it allows both people to respond at different stages, e.g. the response of the original ticket could come from the first person, then if a follow-up question comes, the second could reply etc. (Sorry, can't recommend any particular helpdesk software as I have no extensive experience with any of them).

Comment: If you are bound to using a mail server, you could employ IMAP keywords to tag already processed messages: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-11

Comment: Just for people who might have the same problem. This was the solutino for me: http://osticket.com/